# SQL : Separate new columns from a string which contains multiple languages information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data which contain 2 different language information.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TblName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TblName
    END

CREATE TABLE #TblName (
    JobNum varchar(10)
    ,CommentText nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('F001234','Vietnamese point-1; Vietnamese point-2; Vietnamese point-3; Vietnamese point-4; Vietnamese point-5;  English point-1; English point-2; English point-3; English point-4; English point-5;')
INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('F005678','Vietnamese point-1; English point-2; Vietnamese point-3; English point-1; Vietnamese point-2; English point-3; English point-4')

select * from #TblName
```

and the output is as below:

```
JobNum    CommentText
F001234   Vietnamese point-1; Vietnamese point-2; Vietnamese point-3; Vietnamese point-4; Vietnamese point-5;  English point-1; English point-2; English point-3; English point-4; English point-5;
F005678   Vietnamese point-1; English point-2; Vietnamese point-3; English point-1; Vietnamese point-2; English point-3; English point-4
```

is there a way in SQL query to get output like in 2 different columns for each language information:

[ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCsHK.png)

Thanks in advance to any answer...

Comment: Please add clarity about your data and requirement with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The way you've written the question, it seems that you give the variable it's value from a table. Does this table contain the lines already? If yes, then you don't need to give it to the variable to print, you can just **SELECT** the lines and that way you'll get what you need

Comment: Seems like you really should be fixing your design here and not storing delimited data in it.

Comment: The real time previous data are quietly saved in these format and we can not change as currently those are habituate by the users since long. One way forward is to divide into 2 different columns with language specific information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your question. Can anyone suggest how to make columns inside pivot dynamic?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TblName') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #TblName
    END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableB') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #tableB
    END

CREATE TABLE #TblName (
    JobNum varchar(10)
    ,CommentText nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('F001234','Vietnamese point-1; Vietnamese point-2; Vietnamese point-3; Vietnamese point-4; Vietnamese point-5;  English point-1; English point-2; English point-3; English point-4; English point-5;')
INSERT INTO #TblName VALUES ('F005678','Vietnamese point-1; English point-2; Vietnamese point-3; English point-1; Vietnamese point-2; English point-3; English point-4')

select * from #TblName
```

Next I am loading below result t a temporary table `#tableB`

```
SELECT JobNum, RetVal, SUBSTRING(retval,1,CHARINDEX(' ',retval,0)) Lang 
INTO #tableB 
FROM (
    Select A.JobNum
          ,B.*
    FROM #TblName A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT  RetVal = LTRIM(RTRIM(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From  (
                        SELECT x = CAST('<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(A.CommentText,';','§§Split§§') AS [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')
                        ) as A 
                    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('x') AS B(i)) B
    )t where retval IS NOT NULL

SELECT * from #tableB
```

Finally, expected result is generated here. However, the column names are not dynamic. I will update the code if I find a solution for it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT jobnum,lang, STUFF((
             SELECT ';' + RetVal
                FROM #tableB xx
                WHERE xx.JobNum = xy.JobNum and xx.Lang = xy.Lang
                ORDER BY XX.RetVal
                FOR XML PATH('')
            
             ), 1, 1, '') AS a
             FROM #tableB xy
             GROUP BY JobNum,Lang
    )t
PIVOT (MAX(a) 
    FOR lang IN ([English],[Vietnamese])) piv
```

Comment: thank you... working and got to know this way to achieve the output. Thanks again for this knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH 
T AS
(
select JobNum, LTRIM(value) AS V, LEFT(LTRIM(value), CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(value)) - 1) AS L
from #TblName
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(CommentText, ';')
WHERE LTRIM(value) <> ''
)
SELECT JobNum, 
       CASE WHEN L = 'Vietnamese' THEN RIGHT(V, LEN(V) - CHARINDEX (' ', V)) ELSE NULL END AS Vietnamese,
       CASE WHEN L = 'English' THEN RIGHT(V, LEN(V) - CHARINDEX (' ', V)) ELSE NULL END AS English
FROM   T
```